# How do I avoid over-sizing my class to account for a rare occurrence?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, hierarchy

I'm trying to design a hierarchical transform class for use within my physics engine.
To start, here is a snippet:

```
class Transform
{
public:
  Transform();
  ~Transform();

private:
  glm::mat3x3 local_to_world; // matrix of self and concatenated parents.

  glm::vec2 w_translation; // only needed if the object uses hierarchy
  glm::vec2 w_scale;       // only needed if the object uses hierarchy
  float w_rotation;        // only needed if the object uses hierarchy

  // the local coordinates of the root object are the same as its world coordinates.
  glm::vec2 l_translation;
  glm::vec2 l_scale;
  float l_rotation;

  Transform *parent;    // only needed if the object uses hierarchy
  Transform *root;      // only needed if the object uses hierarchy
  std::forward_list<Transform *> children;     // you guessed it...

  bool modified;

  // an additional problem is that these functions are called after any
  // update to the transform whatsoever, and are totally useless if the
  // object is not using hierarchy
  void update_w_trans();
  void update_w_scale();
  void update_w_rotation();

  // ...
};
```

In practicality, the user would most likely only utilize parenting for a small minority of objects. What this means is that for any object not using parenting, there a decent portion of memory and work going to waste. I feel like this is a big problem considering transforms are a very commonly occurring component.

I have come up with a couple of possible solutions:

1. Throw all of the hierarchy-only data within its own struct and keep a pointer to that on the class.  This would need a *LOT* of null checking within the methods.
2. Build a wrapper class around transforms that contains a transform pointer.  Most methods would be one line and call methods on the pointer, but
   if a method is called that would cause hierarchy (such as add_child), make a one time conversion to a derived class.

I myself am a fairly inexperienced C++/OOP programmer and haven't really run into a problem like this before, but I feel like this has to be a common concept across all OOP.

I was wondering if one or both of these is a commonly used approach, or if there is a much better approach to take toward this problem that will reduce waste whilst still keeping the interface simple?

Comment: Why not inherit and make a separate class that can have children? Of course it has its own overhead, but that's the typical OO way.

Comment: I could, but it would need a wrapper of sorts (i detailed it a bit in solution 2), because many other objects in the simulation point to transforms. Not to mention the user might want to directly access transforms as well. Is doing such a thing with a wrapping class the common solution? I am not perfectly acquainted with the STL, and i feel as though my answer might lie in there, but I'm just not sure.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the two solutions you came up with please? I am not sure to understand the difference between those.

Comment: *"it would ruin the interface"*, all that members are private, so how does that ruin interface ?

Comment: Solution 1 is to make a pointer within the transform class itself that will default to null, but become allocated when a function causing hierarchy is called. then, it would allocate a sub-class containing the hierarchy-only data. So it's only there when it's needed.     Solution 2 is to make a derived class that overrides most of the functions of the base class with the hierarchy stuff, but I believe it would need to be wrapped in another object to achieve this safely.

Comment: Jarod, the snippet I show is not the entire class. That being said, it may not actually ruin the interface, after some thought, but it still feels like a hacky solution, as nearly every method would require a null-check inside of it to see if it's using hierarchy or not. I thought it might ruin the interface because the gettors of certain variables would be pointless, considering the variables are not used without hierarchy in play. I could, however, write conditionals into those gettors to fix it.

Comment: Your `nullptr` check would be equivalent to your current code which should check if it is using hierarchy or not... And if you didn't need to check if it is hierarchy or not, you might still use directly as member (and not as pointer) to self document your class (and get rid of most comments).

Comment: I added those comments for demonstration's sake on the question :p my current code does not do this. Like I said, I know it is a potential solution, but I'm wondering if there is a better one.